# Creating a folder with the character euro as name

Tags: php, special-characters

How can i create a folder named '€' on windows

```
mkdir('&euro;');
mkdir(utf8_decode('€'));
mkdir(utf8_decode('&euro;'));
mkdir('€');
```

Comment: Did you try `xn--lzg` which is **punycode** [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode]

Comment: Thanks Javad, it's created with `include_once('punycode.class.php');
mkdir(Punycode::encodeHostName("€"));`